# Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") does not work in powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I tried to use vba in powerpoint to copy a table from excel to powerpoint, then resize it in powerpoint. However, it prompts out the error "Selection(Unknown number)".
If I save it before resizing, it will work ok. But I don't want to save it. How to solve this issue? Below is my code:

```
sld.Select
sld.Application.Activate
ActiveWindow.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
sld.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
'sld.Application.ActivePresentation.Save

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 7.3 * 72
    .Width = 13.38 * 72
    .Left = 1.45 * 72
    .Top = 1.35 * 72
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With
```

Best,
Alvin

Answer (score 0):

Alvin,

I too encountered this issue. You need to release focus from the commandbars to fix the error. Try adding this below the ExecuteMso line:

```
sld.Application.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
```

Hope this helps.